# Displaying a bipartite graph in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Which is the function that can plot me the bipartite graph $K_{7, 2}$ in *Mathematica*? And after that to delete 2 edges?? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you seen `CompleteGraph[]`?

Comment: It is poor form to edit a question to replace the one originally asked. If you have to ask another one, ask in a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [CompleteGraph](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompleteGraph.html) as suggested by @Guesswhoitis in the comments and 
[EdgeDelete](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EdgeDelete.html):

```
opts = {VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], BaseStyle -> Thick,
   ImageSize -> 300, VertexSize -> {"Scaled", .1}, 
   VertexLabelStyle -> Large};

k72 = CompleteGraph[{7, 2}, opts];
deletededges = {5 \[UndirectedEdge] 9, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 8};
k72b = EdgeDelete[k72, deletededges];

Row[Labeled[##, Top] & @@@ 
    {{k72, Style["k72 = CompleteGraph[{7,2}]", 18, "Panel"]},
     {k72b, Style[ "EdgeDelete[k72, {5\[UndirectedEdge]9, 2\[UndirectedEdge]8}]", 18,
 "Panel"]}}]
```

[image]