# DeleteVertex in Kpartite graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

How can i make K7,2 graph and how can i delete 2 vertex?
Btw, i need to use package -> Combinatorica`;

I tried this:
 
`a = CompleteGraph[7, 2]
DeleteVertex[a, {3, 4}]
ShowGraph[a]`

but it doesn't work ..

Thanks,

Comment: Hi ! Did you try searching this same Q/A about duplicates ?

Comment: I tried some answers from the duplicates, but still none works

Comment: Like this one [`(83009)`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83009/displaying-a-bipartite-graph-in-wolfram-mathematica) ?

Comment: i will try , thanks

Comment: @Sektor, [this Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84154/125) is more related. In either case,  this question seems to be about using ``"Combinatorica`"`` functions `DeleteVertex` and `ShowGraph`. If it is, then it is not a duplicate of the linked Q/As. Angel, please clarify if you need to  use the function `DeleteVertex` (hence, the package `Combinatorica` package) or either of the linked Q/As gives the answer you need.

Comment: Yes i need to use @kguler "Combinatorica` and i want to delete 2 vertexes in 1 step , thats what i need.. 

Thanks anyway

Comment: @kguler Well its really helped me 
Thanks a lot

Comment: @GuzelovAngel, just voted to re-open this question since it is not a duplicate of the linked q/as. Please update your question clarifying why this is not duplicate: i.e. add your requirement that you need to use the `Combinatorica` function `DeleteVertex`.

Comment: @kguler And 1 more thing , 
I need to delete 2 edges from the graph that has already  deleted 2 vertices.
And after all  , i need all my vertices to be green 

Thanks,

Comment: Angel, you should add that  new requirement to your question (specifying the edges you need to delete). You can also ask a new question specifically with that requirement.

Answer (score 2):

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
a = CompleteGraph[7, 2];
```

An alternative, more convenient, `Combinatorica` function is `DeleteVertices`, which takes a list of vertices to be deleted.

The function `DeleteVertex` takes *a single vertex* as the second 
    argument, not a list of vertices. Thus, If you have to use `DeleteVertex`, you need to use `Fold`: delete
    vertex `3` in graph `a`, and, then delete vertex `3` in the resulting 
    graph (which is vertex `4` in the original graph). Alternatively, you can sort the list of vertices-to-be-deleted in descending order in the third argument of `Fold`.

```
b1 = DeleteVertices[a, {3, 4}];
b2 = Fold[DeleteVertex, a, {3, 3}];
(* or b2 = Fold[DeleteVertex, a, {4, 3}]; *)

Row[{ShowGraph[a, VertexStyle -> Disk[.05], VertexColor -> Green, 
   VertexLabel -> (Style[#, 18] & /@ Range[9]), ImageSize -> 300], 
  ShowGraph[b1, VertexStyle -> Disk[.05], VertexColor -> Green, 
   VertexLabel -> (Style[#, 18] & /@ Drop[Range[9], {3, 4}]), ImageSize -> 300],
  ShowGraph[b2, VertexStyle -> Disk[.05], VertexColor -> Green, 
   VertexLabel -> (Style[#, 18] & /@ Drop[Range[9], {3, 4}]), ImageSize -> 300]}]
```

[image]

Comment: @kugler can u check my other question , 
Thanks

Comment: @kugler Thanks a lot mate